# Github Actions - Limit selection to certain branches in "Use Workflow from" dropdown

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to show only the default branch, such as `main` and only a small selection of certain branches. Is this possible? By default, GitHub actions gives the user the ability to select all branches for the Workflow to run against.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to limit that. What are you trying to prevent or achieve?

Comment: I want to only allow for certain branches, like a dev, release or maybe core feature branch to appear in the list only. My hope is to limit the possibility of someone selecting a feature branch or test branch by mistake, as this pipeline is meant to only run against the most stable production ready code.

Comment: You could add checks into the workflow itself, or you could make the workflow check out the branch you want, so it wouldn't really matter where the action is run – as long as the workflow is the same in all branches, that is.